# How do I export multiple views with different filters from Tableau server using tabcmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tableau-api

I am exporting multiple views from tableau server through tabcmd. 
Each view just has a different filter so each command line changes the filter and exports the file. If I run the batch file, the 1st view works, but following views export nothing.
If I copy/paste code into cmd, it works. But simply running the batch file does not.

```
tabcmd export "Book1/View1" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1.pdf"
tabcmd export "Book1/View1?Region=West" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_west.pdf"
tabcmd export "Book1/View1?Region=North" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_North.pdf"
tabcmd export "Book1/View1?Region=East" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_East.pdf"
```

Comment: ALWAYS use full paths. That to tabcmd whatever that is.

Comment: Is `tabcmd` a batch file? if yes, precede `call`...

Comment: @aschipfl, not it is an executable, but not relevant to your question, funny enough the executable states _"This program cannot be run in DOS mode_" :D :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter **--filter** according the documentation of [export](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0)

```
tabcmd export "Book1/View1" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_west.pdf" --filter "Region=West"
tabcmd export "Book1/View1" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_North.pdf" --filter "Region=North"
tabcmd export "Book1/View1" --pdf -f "C:\Temp\folder1\View1_East.pdf" --filter "Region=East"
```